# Why does sscanf not extract all the numbers from this string format properly?

Tags: c, scanf

I am parsing GNSS data and the module [QuecTel BG96](https://sixfab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Quectel_BG96_GNSS_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.1.pdf) I am using has UART serial interface. When trying to extract the data associated with the message most of it can be extracted using `sscanf`, aside from the time.

Here is an example message, the same used in the code below:

```
"\r\n+QGPSLOC: 010842.0,32.04415,5.31028,1.7,55.0,2,150.36,0.0,0.0,
060224,03\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"
```

Just for completeness, here is the interpretation of the fields, as in the manual:

```
+QGPSLOC:<UTC>,<latitude>,<longitude>,<hdop>,<altitude>,<fix>,<cog>,<spkm>,<spkn>,<date>,<nsat> OK
```

- UTC is UTC time.
  Format: `hhmmss.sss` (Quoted from GPGGA sentence).

The issue is that the first set of numbers, representing the time as `hhmmss.sss`, which when extracted are always `0`.

**Expected output:**

```
 240206-010842.000,       32.04415,         5.31028,      1.7,       55.0, 0002,       150.6000,         0.0000, 00000003
```

**My code:**

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* utc_datetime_format =
    "%02u%02u%02u-%02u%02u%02u.%03u";
const char* print_format =
    "%18.18s, %14.5f, %15.5f, %8.1f, %10.1f, %04u, %14.4f, "
    "%14.4f, %08u\n";

typedef struct
{
    uint64_t year : 12;
    uint64_t month : 4;
    uint64_t day : 8;
    uint64_t hour : 8;
    uint64_t minutes : 8;
    uint64_t seconds : 8;
    uint64_t msec : 16;
} DateAndTime_Compressed;

typedef struct
{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} GNSS_Coordinates;

typedef struct
{
    GNSS_Coordinates       coordinates;
    float                  horizontal_precision;
    float                  altitude;
    float                  course_over_ground;
    float                  speed_over_ground_mps;  // m/s
    DateAndTime_Compressed utc_time;
    uint8_t                fix_type;
    uint8_t                num_satellites;
} GNSS_Data;

int GNSS_ParseData(char* buf, GNSS_Data* data)
{
    const char* format =
        "%s %2" PRIu16 "%2" PRIu16 "%2" PRIu16 ".%3" PRIu16
        ",%f,%f,%f,%f,%" PRIu8 ",%3" PRIu16 ".%2" PRIu16
        ",%f,%f,%2" PRIu8 "%2" PRIu8 "%2" PRIu8 ",%" PRIu32
        "%s";
    char front_padding[128] = {0}, back_padding[128] = {0};

    uint16_t year, month, day, hour, minute, second,
        millisecond, cog_deg, cog_min;
    float tmp;

    // For some reason cannot extract hhmmss.sss from
    // message directly
    int ret = sscanf(
        buf, format, front_padding, &hour, &minute, &second,
        &millisecond, &(data->coordinates.latitude),
        &(data->coordinates.longitude),
        &data->horizontal_precision, &data->altitude,
        &data->fix_type, &cog_deg, &cog_min,
        &data->speed_over_ground_mps, &tmp, &day, &month,
        &year, &data->num_satellites, back_padding);
    if (ret != 19)
    {
        // Handle Error (but no error occurs here)
        return -1;
    }
    data->utc_time = (DateAndTime_Compressed){
        .year    = year,
        .month   = month,
        .day     = day,
        .hour    = hour,
        .minutes = minute,
        .seconds = second,
        .msec    = millisecond};

    data->speed_over_ground_mps *=
        (1000.0f / 3600.0f);  // kph to mps
    data->course_over_ground =
        (float)cog_deg + (((float)cog_min) / 60.0f) /
                             100.0f;  // ddd.mm to ddd.dd

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[] =
        "\r\n+QGPSLOC: "
        "010842.0,32.04415,5.31028,1.7,55.0,2,150.36,0.0,0."
        "0,060224,03\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";

    GNSS_Data gnss_data = {0};

    int ret = GNSS_ParseData(
        msg,
        &gnss_data);  // ret = 0 but data.utc_time wrong
                      // (dates are correct, times wrong)
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to parse data\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char utc_date_string[64] = {0};
    snprintf(
        utc_date_string, 32, utc_datetime_format,
        gnss_data.utc_time.year, gnss_data.utc_time.month,
        gnss_data.utc_time.day, gnss_data.utc_time.hour,
        gnss_data.utc_time.minutes,
        gnss_data.utc_time.seconds,
        gnss_data.utc_time.msec);

    printf(
        print_format, utc_date_string,
        gnss_data.coordinates.latitude,
        gnss_data.coordinates.longitude,
        gnss_data.horizontal_precision, gnss_data.altitude,
        gnss_data.fix_type, gnss_data.course_over_ground,
        gnss_data.speed_over_ground_mps,
        gnss_data.num_satellites);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see `"010842.0"` tried to be parsed by `"%2"PRIu16"%2"PRIu16"%2"PRIu16".%3"PRIu16"` (1 received fractional digit vs 3 expected fractional digits). Is that what you want?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including output of the return value and the values of each of the items.

Comment: You can't use `scanf` for it.  You need to write your own parsing function  some fields can me missing.    `,,,,5.45,,,54`. `scanf` will not parse it.

Comment: If whoever closed this question could reopen it that'd be grand

Comment: @lrdewaal as stated in the second comment, you need to [edit] and provide a [mcve] (a self contained console program, that can be copy/pasted/compiled and run and that demonstrates the issue). The the question will most likely be reopened. BTW I didn't close vote.

Comment: I regret to inform you that you have rediscovered one of the several reasons why you should [never use any of the `*scanf` functions for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf). The linked question and the various things it links to can help you understand what to do instead.

Comment: @thebusybee I tried it by changing the expected digits to 1 and 2 but it does not make a difference

Comment: You are assuming this values are in fact `float`. They are not. Just parse the string as the text using `.` and `,` as delimiters and `sscanf` will work ok

Comment: While waiting for reopening, you might consider to delete this post. It is a simple typo: you use `PRN...` in place of `SCN...`, which results in erroneous formats. Additionally the widths do not match the data types. -- Anyway, if you are interested in the reason _why_ you receive these zeroes, keep it and wait for the reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of error in your format string for `sscanf()`:

1. You use `PRN...` instead of `SCN...`. The former are for the `printf()` family, and you need to use the latter. See below for the differences.
2. The used widths of the format specifiers do not match the widths of the variables.

So the correct format is:

```c
    const char* format =
        "%s %2" SCNu16 "%2" SCNu16 "%2" SCNu16 ".%3" SCNu16
        ",%f,%f,%f,%f,%" SCNu8 ",%3" SCNu16 ".%2" SCNu16
        ",%f,%f,%2" SCNu16 "%2" SCNu16 "%2" SCNu16 ",%" SCNu8
        "%s";
```

***NOTE: Please use always the maximum set of warning flags for your compiler.***

---

Now, why do you get zeroes for some time variables?

For this we assume that you are using a standard compiler on a current system, so I use GCC on Windows 10 for investigation.

This little test program shows the differences between the format constants:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("PRIu16 = \"%s\"\n", PRIu16);
  printf("SCNu16 = \"%s\"\n", SCNu16);
  uint16_t canary1 = 0x1122, value, canary2 = 0x5566;
  // 0x3344 = 13124
  printf("sscanf() = %d\n", sscanf("13124", "%" PRIu16, &value));
  printf("canary1 @%p = %04X\n", (void*)&canary1, canary1);
  printf("value   @%p = %04X\n", (void*)&value, value);
  printf("canary2 @%p = %04X\n", (void*)&canary2, canary2);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation with a common set of warning flags tells us already that something is wrong:

```
> gcc -Wall -pedantic formats.c -o formats.exe
formats.c: In function 'main':
formats.c:9:45: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int *', but argument 3 has type 'uint16_t *' {aka 'short unsigned int *'} [-Wformat=]
   printf("sscanf() = %d\n", sscanf("13124", "%" PRIu16, &value));
                                             ^~~         ~~~~~~
In file included from formats.c:1:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/inttypes.h:92:17: note: format string is defined here
 #define PRIu16 "u"
formats.c:9:45: warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int *', but argument 3 has type 'uint16_t *' {aka 'short unsigned int *'} [-Wformat=]
   printf("sscanf() = %d\n", sscanf("13124", "%" PRIu16, &value));
                                             ^~~         ~~~~~~
In file included from formats.c:1:
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/inttypes.h:92:17: note: format string is defined here
 #define PRIu16 "u"
```

And the result reproduces your observation, `canary1` is zeroed:

```
> formats.exe
PRIu16 = "u"
SCNu16 = "hu"
sscanf() = 1
canary1 @000000000061FE1E = 0000
value   @000000000061FE1C = 3344
canary2 @000000000061FE1A = 5566
```

We see that `PRIu16` is actually `"u"`, which `sscanf()` uses to write to an `unsigned int`. On our systems, this has usually the same width as `uint32_t`. So `sscanf()` happily writes 4 bytes, overwriting `canary1`.

Which variable gets overwritten depends on the order of the variables in the memory and the sequence by which the values are stored. None of these order/sequence are defined by the standard, so I used two canaries on both sides.

This explains the zeroes you observe.

---

But why is `PRIu16` associated with `unsigned int`, when `SCNu16` is associated with `unsigned short int`?

The secret is the *integer promotion* of integer arguments on variadic functions. And `printf()` is such a variadic function.

If you give a `uint16_t` value to `printf()`, it will be converted to an `int`. As `int` commonly suffices to hold all potential values of `uint16_t`, the conversion result is not an `unsigned int`. However, the bit pattern is identical for both types in the value range of `uint16_t`.

So `printf()` *needs* `"u"` to print such values correctly.

On the other hand, `scanf()` must not write beyond the space of the provided variable. So it *needs* to know the width, which leads to `"hu"`.

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about this difference! Your explanation was on-point, don't think I'll make this mistake again

Answer (score 0):

As documented in *the busybee*'s answer, the main problems are

- the use of `PRN...` instead of `SCN...` for the `sscanf` format,
- the inconsistent widths of the format specifiers that do not match the widths of the variables.

Note also these other problems:

- using a string variable instead of a string literal for the format argument in `printf` and `scanf` functions prevents the compiler from type-checking the arguments against the format string.  This would have spotted the problem in **gcc** and **clang** with the `-Wall`.
- the way you parse the time and date numbers is unreliable: for example a time expressed with 5 digits and 2 decimals as `12345.12` will be interpreted as `12:34:05.012` instead of `1:23:45.120`. You should use a different approach: parse the time and date fields as strings of digits, pad them with leading zeroes and reparse them with a fixed format, handle the number of digits in the milliseconds field explicitly.
- it would be simpler and more reliable to use `int` and `unsigned` temporary variables to parse the input string, then perform extra validations before storing the values into the structure.
- to avoid unit conversion issues, use a local variable with an explicit name for the ground speed and only store the converted value into the structure.
- I don't know if the `course_over_ground` can be negative, but in this case, the minutes must be negated in the conversion formula. Furthermore, the conversion of the minutes part is incorrect: you should just use `(float)cog_deg + (float)cog_min / 60.0f`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UTC_DATETIME_FORMAT  "%02u%02u%02u-%02u%02u%02u.%03u"
#define PRINT_FORMAT  "%18.18s, %14.5f, %15.5f, %8.1f, %10.1f, %04u, %14.4f, %14.4f, %08u\n"

typedef struct {
    uint64_t year : 12;
    uint64_t month : 4;
    uint64_t day : 8;
    uint64_t hour : 8;
    uint64_t minutes : 8;
    uint64_t seconds : 8;
    uint64_t msec : 16;
} DateAndTime_Compressed;

typedef struct {
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} GNSS_Coordinates;

typedef struct {
    GNSS_Coordinates       coordinates;
    float                  horizontal_precision;
    float                  altitude;
    float                  course_over_ground;
    float                  speed_over_ground_mps;  // m/s
    DateAndTime_Compressed utc_time;
    uint8_t                fix_type;
    uint8_t                num_satellites;
} GNSS_Data;

int GNSS_ParseData(const char *buf, GNSS_Data *data)
{
    char back_padding[128] = { 0 };
    char hhmmss_buf[5+6+1] = "00000";
    char ddmmyy_buf[5+6+1] = "00000";
    char msec_buf[4] = { 0 };
    unsigned year, month, day, hour, minute, second, msec;
    int cog_deg;
    unsigned fix_type, cog_min, num_satellites;
    float speed_over_ground_kph, tmp;

    int ret = sscanf(buf,
                     "%*127s %6[0-9].%3[0-9],%f,%f,%f,%f,%u,%d.%u,%f,%f,%6[0-9],%u %127s",
                     hhmmss_buf + 5, msec_buf,
                     &data->coordinates.latitude, &data->coordinates.longitude,
                     &data->horizontal_precision, &data->altitude,
                     &fix_type, &cog_deg, &cog_min, &speed_over_ground_kph,
                     &tmp, ddmmyy_buf + 5, &num_satellites, back_padding);
    if (ret != 14)
        return -1;

    // pad the time string with leading zeroes
    sscanf(hhmmss_buf + strlen(hhmmss_buf) - 6,
           "%02u%02u%02u", &hour, &minute, &second);
    if (second >= 60 || minute >= 60 || hour >= 24)
        return -3;
    // pad the date string with leading zeroes
    sscanf(ddmmyy_buf + strlen(ddmmyy_buf) - 6,
           "%02u%02u%02u", &day, &month, &year);
    if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 31 || year > 99)
        return -4;

    msec = (msec_buf[0] - '0') * 100;
    if (msec_buf[1] != '\0') {
        msec += (msec_buf[1] - '0') * 10;
        if (msec_buf[2] != '\0')
            msec += (msec_buf[2] - '0');
    }

    if (fix_type > 255)
        return -5;
    if (num_satellites > 255)
        return -6;

    data->utc_time = (DateAndTime_Compressed){
        .year    = year,
        .month   = month,
        .day     = day,
        .hour    = hour,
        .minutes = minute,
        .seconds = second,
        .msec    = msec
    };
    data->fix_type = (uint8_t)fix_type;
    data->num_satellites = (uint8_t)num_satellites;
    // make the unit conversion explicit: km/h to m/s
    data->speed_over_ground_mps = speed_over_ground_kph * (1000.0f / 3600.0f);
    // convert ddd.mm to ddd.dd, accept negative angles
    if (cog_deg < 0)
        cog_min = -cog_min;
    data->course_over_ground = (float)cog_deg + (float)cog_min / 60.0f;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[] =
        "\r\n+QGPSLOC: "
        "010842.0,32.04415,5.31028,1.7,55.0,2,150.36,0.0,0."
        "0,060224,03\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";

    GNSS_Data gnss_data = { 0 };

    int ret = GNSS_ParseData(msg, &gnss_data);  // ret = 0 but data.utc_time wrong
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Failed to parse data: error %d\n", -ret);
        return -1;
    }
    char utc_date_string[32] = { 0 };
    // use explicit casts to avoid compiler warnings
    snprintf(utc_date_string, sizeof utc_date_string,
             UTC_DATETIME_FORMAT,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.year,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.month,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.day,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.hour,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.minutes,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.seconds,
             (unsigned)gnss_data.utc_time.msec);

    // use explicit casts to avoid compiler warnings
    printf(PRINT_FORMAT, utc_date_string,
           (double)gnss_data.coordinates.latitude,
           (double)gnss_data.coordinates.longitude,
           (double)gnss_data.horizontal_precision,
           (double)gnss_data.altitude,
           (unsigned)gnss_data.fix_type,
           (double)gnss_data.course_over_ground,
           (double)gnss_data.speed_over_ground_mps,
           (unsigned)gnss_data.num_satellites);

    return 0;
}
```